# Does there exist a nontrivial abelian group $A$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(A) \cong A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups, automorphism-group

Does there exist a nontrivial abelian group $A$, such that $\mathrm{Aut}(A) \cong A$? Here $\mathrm{Aut}$ stands for the automorphism group.

What do I currently know:

> If such $A$ exists, it has infinite exponent.

It follows from the first Prüfer theorem, that every bounded exponent noncyclic abelian group has non-abelian automorphism group. A cyclic group is isomorphic to its automorphism group iff it is trivial.

> If such $A$ exists, it is infinitely generated.

It follows from the classification of finitely-generated abelian groups, that every finitely generated noncyclic abelian group has non-abelian automorphism group. A cyclic group is isomorphic to its automorphism group iff it is trivial.